# How can I implement a hold button that calls a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, button

I need to implement a button and when I click and hold it for 5 seconds, it calls a JavaScript function, and when I release the button it cancels the call. How can I do that?

Something like this:

[image: code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle that will trigger an alert if you hold the button for 5 seconds but will not call the alert if you release the button before 5 seconds are over.
This is done by setting a timeout when you click down on the button, but clearing the timeout once you release the button.
(uses jquery)

https://jsfiddle.net/ehozjeLn/1/

```
 <div>
  <input id="btnTesting" type="button" value="test" />
</div>

$('#btnTesting').mousedown(function(){
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 5000);
});

$('#btnTesting').mouseup(function(){
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var Handler = function() {
       // create a function which sets an action to handle in 5 seconds.
       this.clickHandler = function() {
          var self = this;
          this.timerId = setTimeout(function() {
              console.log('fired!!!!');
              self.timerId = null;
              // do whatever here.
          },5000)
       };
       
       //creat a function which will cancel the previously scheduled task.
       this.cancelHandler = function() {
           // fire cancel logic if needed
           if (this.timerId) {
               console.log('cancelling');
               clearTimeout(this.timerId);
           }
       }
    }


 
var h = new Handler();

//find an element to attach the event to.
var button = document.querySelector('button');

//wire up your event handlers to your element
button.addEventListener('mousedown', h.clickHandler.bind(h));

button.addEventListener('mouseup', h.cancelHandler.bind(h));
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```